# Is there any way to remove fitVids() from an element after it's been applied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, responsive-design, fitvids

I am using [FitVids](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js/blob/master/README.md) for reponsive video. I instantiate it like this:

```
$("#thing-with-videos").fitVids();
```

I want `fitVids()` to be applied to one particular element at screen sizes below 480px and I have implemented that. However for display purposes I also need `fitVids()` to apply if the user resizes the browser to check the display in a small width, and I have done that something like this

```
jQuery(window).resize( function(){
    $("#other-thing-with-videos.small_width").fitVids();            
});
```

... which works fine, however, as `fitVids()` seems to be applied to the referenced DOM element, as opposed to the referencing class like I first thought, it means that removing the class (for wider screen sizes) doesn't remove the effects of `fitVids()` like I thought.

So is there any way to remove `fitVids()` that I called on the element?

EDIT - I was wondering if the [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) method could be used for this?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle example?

Comment: @HanletEscaño It's pretty complex and built with bootstrap wordpress and flexslider ... it would take and awe-full long time to create a reduced test case ... thanks though.

Comment: @HanletEscaño Sorry I just realized I'm talking nonsense and I dont need all that other stuff from the project in a fiddle at all. Here's one http://jsfiddle.net/byronyasgur/m6Jwx/ ... What I want to do is remove fitVids() from `#container` via JS after it's been applied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will remove the class and any style to the parent div:

```
$('#container').fitVids();
$("#btn").click(function () 
{
    $(".fluid-width-video-wrapper").removeClass("fluid-width-video-wrapper").removeAttr("style");
});
```

That pretty much removes the FitVid effect.

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/m6Jwx/1/

**Edit**: I think this solution works a bit better:

```
$.fn.unFitVids = function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var $children = $("#" + id + " .fluid-width-video-wrapper").children().clone();
    $("#" + id + " .fluid-width-video-wrapper").remove(); //removes the element
    $("#" + id).append($children); //adds it to the parent
};
```

And you just call it from your element like this:

```
$("#myDiv").unFitVids();
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/m6Jwx/2/

The only disadvantage I can see, is that because I remove the elements from the DOM, clone them, and put them in the div parent, if the video is already playing, it will stop.

Comment: Wow ... nicely thought of.

Comment: Thanks for that additon ... actually in the meantime I found that (presumably because of my CSS rules ) I also needed to remove the div element itself too ... so I managed to do it using an `unwrap()` on the iframe if the parent was `.fluid-width-video-wrapper`. Thanks again I never would have thought of this way of looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

Hanlets code is a good idea, but it assumes you only have 1 video in your selector.

Below extended code loops through all video's

```
$.fn.unFitVids = function () {
    $.each(this, function(i, el){
        var $wrapper = $(".fluid-width-video-wrapper", el),
            $children = $wrapper.children().clone();
        $wrapper.remove();
        $(el).append($children);
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
$(".fluid-width-video-wrapper iframe").unwrap();
```

But ".fluid-width-video-wrapper" is applied after some delay (after document load), so you can fire the function after some delay

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $(".fluid-width-video-wrapper iframe").unwrap()
}, 300);
```